# Javascript date countdown with custom date

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var timer;

var compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.setDate(Date.parse('2020-06-02'));

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = toDate;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);
  
  } else {
    
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
#timer {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #999;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#timer span {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 3px 0 15px;
}
#timer span:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">
  <span id="days"></span>days
  <span id="hours"></span>hours
  <span id="minutes"></span>minutes
  <span id="seconds"></span>seconds
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add more details? just having a code snippet and title doesn't mean people understand what the output should be, please check  [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setDate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp) sets only Day of the current month in date object. You can directly provide your date string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format to `Date()` while creating new object.

```js
var timer;

var compareDate = new Date('2020-06-02');
// compareDate.setDate(Date.parse('2020-06-02'));

timer = setInterval(function() {
  timeBetweenDates(compareDate);
}, 1000);

function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {
  var dateEntered = toDate;
  var now = new Date();
  var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();

  if (difference <= 0) {

    // Timer done
    clearInterval(timer);
  
  } else {
    
    var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

    hours %= 24;
    minutes %= 60;
    seconds %= 60;

    $("#days").text(days);
    $("#hours").text(hours);
    $("#minutes").text(minutes);
    $("#seconds").text(seconds);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
#timer {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #999;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
#timer span {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0 3px 0 15px;
}
#timer span:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="timer">
  <span id="days"></span>days
  <span id="hours"></span>hours
  <span id="minutes"></span>minutes
  <span id="seconds"></span>seconds
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly set new Date()

```
var compareDate = new Date('2020-06-02');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
var compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.setDate(Date.parse('2020-06-02'));
```

to

```
var compareDate = new Date(2020, 05, 2);
```